# FinancialData[]: Version 11.3 versus 12

Tags: curated-data, finance

Something go wrong with `FinancialData[]`

In version 11.3, when I import data like

```
FD = FinancialData["AS:AALB", "Close", {{2017, 01, 01}, {2019, 03, 31}}]
```

The result is a dataset like: {{2017, 1, 2}, 31.13}, {{2017, 1, 3}, 31.005}, {{2017, 1, 4}, 30.965}

In version 12 the result is a `TimeSeries`.

After the import, I usualy export the data to a SQL database.  Now I have to use different steps. The problem is that the new version is not stable and each time I want to manipulate the dataset before export, my notebooks quit.

anybody recognise this issue?

Comment: Michiel, you describe the output of a `TimeSeries` but then you talk about difficulties exporting a `Dataset`. Could you give an example for what exactly does not work (so it can be reproduced)? On what machine are you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried wrapping the `TimeSeries` with `Normal`?

By which I mean, something like this:

```
FD = FinancialData["AS:AALB", "Close", {{2017, 01, 01}, {2019, 03, 31}}];

Normal[FD] /. {d_DateObject :> DateList[d][[;; 3]], q_Quantity :> QuantityMagnitude[q]}
```

Yields:

```
{{{2017, 1, 2}, 31.13}, {{2017, 1, 3}, 31.005}, {{2017, 1, 4}, 
  30.965}, {{2017, 1, 5}, 31.035}, {{2017, 1, 6}, 
  30.745}, {{2017, 1, 9}, 30.75}, {{2017, 1, 10}, 
  30.49}, {{2017, 1, 11}, 30.56}, {{2017, 1, 12}, 30.37},...
```